# node js mongoose find inside nested mixed property?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema like this.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
      t: {type: Date, required: true},
      o: {type: String, required: true},
      d: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true}
    }
```

the objects in mongoDb are like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d36948b7f40460dd0d28934"),
    "t" : ISODate("2019-07-23T05:00:59.518Z"), 
    "o" : "u",
    "d" : {
        "room" : "5c0508cd12e0fc3310a8ba00",
        "noOfTimesSwapped" : 4,
        "modifiedAt" : "2019-07-23T05:00:59.517Z",
        "modifiedBy" : "5c73d5f2e4c2754e0cd5246a",
        "p" : {
            "_id" : "5d35bac67660ad2dd8fbb57d"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the records which matches with the _id of the 'p' field which is a property of d.

I have tried to get records using the following criteria, but that does not work.

```
MyModel.find({ 'd.p._id': id }, function (err, docs) {});
```

Comment: It seems `_id` inside p is a string and you are finding through ObjectId. Can you clarify `id` is string or ObjectId?

Comment: for the query i'am supplying it as a string.

Comment: If it is String then `.find({ 'd.p._id': "5d35bac67660ad2dd8fbb57d" })` working perfectly in my case by given your sample data

Comment: Check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/